# errors: expo-camera.isAvailableAsync and expo-camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync is not available on android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

expo-camera: "^8.0.0"

sdkVersion: "36.0.0"

Hello people, when i try:

```
    import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
    ...
    const cameraIsAvailable = await Camera.isAvailableAsync()
    const availablesCameraTypes = await Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync()
    console.log("cameraIsAvailable: ", cameraIsAvailable)
    console.log("availablesCameraTypes: ", availablesCameraTypes)
```

i get the fallowing errors:

1. expo-camera.isAvailableAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?
2. The method or property expo-camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?

[image]
[image]

the problem just disappear when i remove:

```
state = {
    ...
    cameraType: Camera.Constants.Type.front,
  };
... 
<Camera
            type={this.state.cameraType}
            flashMode={flashMode}
            style={styles.preview}
            ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
          />
```

and change it by:

```
state = {
    ...
    cameraType: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  };
```

and i change "cameraType" by

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', async () => {
      await setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ cameraType: Camera.Constants.Type.front })
      }, 100)
    });
  }
```

it seems its an error from expo-camera...
so when i try to call these methods:

```
const cameraIsAvailable = await Camera.isAvailableAsync()
    const availablesCameraTypes = await Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync()
```

i get following errors: [errors: expo-camera.isAvailableAsync and expo-camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync is not available on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527740/errors-expo-camera-isavailableasync-and-expo-camera-getavailablecameratypesasyn)

Comment: Have you installed it properly? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/
Are you by any chance testing this on a simulator?

Comment: @PetrBela look to my edits and see expo-camera behavior..

Comment: @PetrBela yes i installed it propertly, with simulator i cannot use camera propertly..

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing a similar issue and would be glad to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you're trying to use, [`Camera.isAvailableAsync`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#cameraisavailableasync-boolean) and [`Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#cameragetavailablecameratypesasync-string) are marked in the documentation as *Web only*, so calling them will only work, well, on Web.

In code run in `react-native` context (as opposed to browser context) just check permissions and you should be good to go!

[image: Documentation screenshot]